# exim: redirect all but a number of local parts

Tags: redirect, exim, regex, wildcard

On my server, I implement redirects using this router

```
virtual_aliases:
  driver = redirect
  allow_defer
  allow_fail
  data = ${lookup{$local_part@$domain}wildlsearch*@{/etc/vhosts/forwards}}
  domains = /etc/vhosts/maildomains
  qualify_preserve_domain
  retry_use_local_part
```

and entries in `/etc/vhosts/forwards` like

```
foo@example.com: bar@example.com
^.*@example2.com: bar@example.com
```

This works fine and as intended. Now my customer asks me to change the second line to “forward all, with the exception of mail@example2.com and info@example2.com”, as these attract too much spam.

Is there a nice way to implement this logic inside the `/etc/vhosts/forwards`, or would I have to add another blacklisting router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can selectively bounce email in the alias file /etc/vhosts/forwards, or just have it disappear. See [the documentation on special items in lists](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_redirect_router.html#SECTspecitredli), aka alias files (bullet items 4 & 5 as of Oct-14-2015).

```
# efficiently and silently discard this email after accepting it 
mail@example2.com: :blackhole:

# bounce this email. message is optional. 
info@example2.com: :fail: User no longer available

# forward the rest 
foo@example.com: bar@example.com 
^.*@example2.com: bar@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks. Where is `:blackhole:` and `:fail:` documented?

Comment: For Exim4, it is documented here in the 4th and 5th bullet items: http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_redirect_router.html#SECTspecitredli

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to update your answer with that information, so that it is not hidden in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a condition to the router:

```
virtual_aliases:
  driver = redirect
  allow_defer
  allow_fail
  condition = ${lookup{$local_part@$domain}wildlsearch*@{/etc/vhosts/stoplist}{no}{yes}}
  data = ${lookup{$local_part@$domain}wildlsearch*@{/etc/vhosts/forwards}}
  domains = /etc/vhosts/maildomains
  qualify_preserve_domain
  retry_use_local_part
```

If address is listed in the `/etc/vhosts/stoplist` no redirection will be performed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is possible within the `forwards` file, by specifying no addresses to forward to:

```
foo@example.com: bar@example.com
mail@example2.com:
info@example2.com:
^.*@example2.com: bar@example.com
```

This seems to be documented behavior (and not just a lucky implementation detail):

> If the lookup fails, the expanded string in this example is empty. When the expansion of data results in an empty string, the router declines. A forced expansion failure also causes the router to decline; other expansion failures cause delivery to be deferred. [Source](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_redirect_router.html)